Broken xorg.conf.d file (modified with $ sudo gedit 10-nvidia.conf)
I modified my xorg.conf.d using:
    $ sudo gedit 10-nvidia.conf

I added:
    Section "ServerFlags"
        Option "AllowIndirectGLX" "on"
        Option "IndirectGLX" "on"
    EndSection
    Section “Monitor”
        Option …(forgot the code here)
    EndSection

Upon restart Ubuntu 20.04 would boot into the login screen but after entering password it would just return back to the login screen to enter password.
Can I delete my additions from command line in recovery mode? Or is there another easy method?

You probably don't even need recovery mode - just use one of the CLI virtual terminals (ex. Ctrl-Alt-F6)
